# How to restore datasources for TFS reports?

Tags: tfs, ssrs-2008

The following is the case: I have a TFS2008 installation. on a machine named TFS1 the databases are located on: DB1. Since friday I'm not able to connect to the reports anymore.

This happened to be the day that I changed my password. When I open the "reporting services configuration" I noticed that the TFS1 was not initialized. I'd manageed to initialise the reporting service.

Now I got the message: "The report server is unable to access encrypted data. Apply a back-up key or delete all encrypted content. (rsEncryptedDataUnavailable) (rsRPCError)"

I've had this problem before and I did delete the encrypted content at that time. This deleted a crucial CRM report what took us 3 weeks to recover. So I'm not really into that option. The only thing that I know of that is encrypted are the reporting datasources.

Is there an easy way to resolve this error? I was thinking about reinstalling the reporting services for TFS. Can I do this without interrupting the reporting for CRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it the following way:

I created two new Datasources: TfsOlapReportNEW & TfsReportNEW with the following settings:

```
"TfsOlapReportNEW"
Select "Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services"
Place in the connection string "Data source=<SERVER>;initial catalog=TfsWarehouse"
Select "Credentials stored securely in the report server"
Enter the correct credentials for access
select "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source"

"TfsReportNEW"
Select "Microsoft SQL Server"
Place in the connection string "Data source=<SERVER>;initial catalog=TfsWarehouse"
Select "Credentials stored securely in the report server"
Enter the correct credentials for access
select "Use as Windows credentials when connecting to the data source"
```

In the report select properties > datasources. Select the newly created datasources accordingly and click apply.